# Make a module editable when page in DNN is not in Edit Mode

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I have a page 'Page 1' to which I have added a custom module called 'Exam Tracker'.

Is there a way to make this module on 'Page 1' always editable, even when 'Page 1' is not in edit mode? May be some configuration, but I have not got it to work.

This would be useful to allow certain users, who cannot edit the page, to be able to edit this module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So there are a couple of ways you might go about this, but here is probably the easiest way.

Basically you need to do the following, you need to create a hyperlink that goes to your EDIT control for your module. If you put that hyperlink into the VIEW control for your module, anyone will be able to click on it, and will be taken to the EDIT interface.

DotNetNuke will still require that the user has EDIT permissions for the module, if not, they won't be able to access the resulting page generated by the link, they will either be prompted to login, or they will be told they don't have access to that page.

I would recommend that you wrap that link in some sort of permissions check though, that way you don't display it to everyone visiting the page, just the people who should have access to it.